# Pandas groupby get first element of group where row matches criteria

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe where some rows have all the same values except for one column. I wish to remove duplicate rows, keeping only the first row in each group whose value in that column is 1, or one arbitrary row if no values in that column are 1. Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                   'b': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'c': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

And my desired output is something like

```
df.groupby(['a']).first_where(lambda row: row['c'] == 1).reset_index()

  a b c
0 1 1 1
1 2 4 0
2 3 5 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['a','c']).drop_duplicates(['a'],keep='last')
Out[748]: 
   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
4  2  4  0
6  3  6  1
```

If you want to use `groupby`

```
df.sort_values(['a','c']).groupby('a',as_index=False).last()
Out[750]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  4  0
2  3  6  1
```

Comment: Is it possible to restore the original sort order of the dataframe, if it's sorted arbitrarily?

Comment: @BallpointBen yes, then you can look at op1 , you can sort index , index do not change by using sort_index() at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by your criteria first, and then do the groupby:

```
df[df['c'] == 1].groupby('a').head(1)
```